Migrate Custom Function to Hibernate 6
I'm migrating from Hibernate 5 to Hibernate 6 and I have couple problems with Custom Functions.
I have Custom function SINGLE_COLUMN_FROM_JSON_TABLE which is registered in two dialects Oracle and H2.
Functions is used in In Clause
select t from TestTable t WHERE t.id IN ( SINGLE_COLUMN_FROM_JSON_TABLE(?1) )

and in oracle Dialect it translates to
select t from TestTable t WHERE t.id IN (
    select single_value from json_table(?1 , '$[*]' COLUMNS ( single_value number PATH '$')) sinval_table)

)
And it's works fine
In H2 Dialect I just want to function translate to
select t from TestTable t WHERE t.id IN ( ?,?,? )

But I have a problem becouse parameters are wrapped in additonal () as
  select t from TestTable t WHERE t.id IN (( ?,?,?))

which is causing error
in ((?,?))"], "params":[["1","2"]]}
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Data conversion error converting "ROW (1, 2)"; SQL statement:
My function implementation for H2 Dialect is very simple
 @Override
    public void render(SqlAppender sqlAppender, List<? extends SqlAstNode> arguments, ReturnableType<?> returnType, SqlAstTranslator<?> translator) {
        translator.render(arguments.get(0), SqlAstNodeRenderingMode.DEFAULT);
    }

Any easy way to render parameters without additional () in H2 Dialect ?
Also I want to use function for String and Integers
string IN ( SINGLE_COLUMN_FROM_JSON_TABLE(?1) )
integer IN ( SINGLE_COLUMN_FROM_JSON_TABLE(?1) )

But such a queries do not pass validation.
As Returned type For Now I have
    public ReturnableType<?> resolveFunctionReturnType(ReturnableType<?> impliedType, List<? extends SqmTypedNode<?>> arguments, TypeConfiguration typeConfiguration) {
            return typeConfiguration.getBasicTypeRegistry().getRegisteredType(Long.class);
        }

Can I implement some custom return type so validation will pass for String and Integers ?
